# Why exactly is bind(this) necessary in React constructors?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-class

It's common knowledge that when defining a React component, you need to bind your class methods inside the class constructor in order to be able to access `this.props`, etc. inside those methods.

My question is simply "why?" In JS, isn't `this` defined to be the method's object when calling the function as a method on an object?

Comment: Depends on how the function is called.

Comment: *"In JS, isn't `this` defined to be the method's object when calling the function as a method on an object?"* That's right. But event handlers are usually not called as methods. You are just passing a function as event handler and the event handling systems calls that function like a normal function (it cannot do anything else). So it's on you to ensure that `this` is correct in your event handler. If the method is not used as event handler then it's likely not necessary to `.bind` it.

Comment: Thanks, @FelixKling! That made sense.